# Laravel 5.2 Authentication functions

Tags: laravel-5, web-applications

I am trying to check if the user is active then redirect it to the application and if the user is not active then keep the user on login page saying "your account has been disabled or you dont have a valid account. Please contact your admin". I am done with the whole application but this is the only thing I cant be able to understand. I tried it Handler.php, tried writing postLogin(), getLogin() functions, changed the route too but still cant be able to figure out. This authentication method of laravel is so confusing as we dont know where the functions are. Any help would be much appreciated.

## Routes

```
// Route::auth();

Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

## AuthController

In `postLogin()` I am just checking whether it goes in to the function or not but it not going in either of the functions if I comment out `route::auth()`

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    echo "getting in this function";
}

public function getLogin($id)
{
    echo "getting in to this function";
    $users = User::find($id);

    if($users->is_active == 1) {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');

    } else {
            Session::flash("message", "Authentication failed. Please contact your admin.");
            return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, first I would suggest to use Laravel's default route and controllers for authentication and then amend it as per the need.

This will surely work:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::auth();
```

**Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $remember = $request->input('remember') ? true : false;

    if ($user = Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
        if(Auth::user()->is_active == 1) {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        } else {
            Auth::logout();
            Session::flash("message", "Authentication failed. Please contact your admin.");
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    } else {
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working ... getting this error`Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist` even after using `use App\Http\Requests;` ... I tried to use this too but it didnt work either  `public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'is_active' => 1])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }`